# how to fix "out of range" problem

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have a dell dimension 4550 with ubuntu 12.04 installed along with Windows Xp. Before the GRUB screen appears, I get the out of range message on my monitor. After a few seconds a dialog box appears, I have to use the CTRL+ALT+(-) to read it due to my monitor resolution not being detected. It says something along the lines of running in low graphics mode. After a few options, I select trouble shoot and nothing happens. So I hit cancel and it returns to out of range. Therefore I cannot see or access the grub to load Windows. If I switched monitors would that fix my problem? I currently have a benq 700x584 I think and plan on moving to a 1024x768 moniter.

Answer (score 0):

You need Minimum Resolution of 1024x768

Here is the Ubuntu 12.04 System Requirements

```
Minimum
Precise Pangolin (12.04.3 32-bit)

384 MB of RAM
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
5 GB of hard-drive space
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Precise Pangolin (12.04.3 64-bit)

1 GB of RAM
Dual Core processor
10 GB of hard-drive space or SSD (the more hard disk capacity, the better)
Any graphics card with OpenGL 1.4 support (All GPUs released today by either NVidia, AMD or Intel; GPUs released by NVidia and AMD over the last 5 years; GPUs released by Intel after the GMA 950)
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful
```